# Select box Click event is not working in C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I need to change the drop down value by using c# Selenium.In select box I have two values.

I'm able to get the options. But I need to **set the option to that drop down**.

please refer the Code Snippets: [View tried codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5AHW.png)

If I use Method 1 I'm getting the following Error.

**Cannot click on option element.Executing javascript function returned an un expected error,but no error could be returned from IE's javascript Enginge.**

If I use the Method 2 or Method 3 Or method 4.I'm not getting any errors but Couldn't set the values in dropdown.

Need your valuable suggestions to overcome the issue. Thanks in Advance

[Html Select box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEabi.png)

Comment: You should include your code as text in this question instead of posting links to images.

Comment: You should include the relevant `HTML` for further analysis.

Comment: @DebanjanB updated the selectbox Html in Question area.

Comment: Is there any chance there is an alert open that is preventing selenium from working and "locks" the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `SelectElement` from the IWebElement and you should be able to click an option by value

```
var select = new SelectElement(ieWebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("yourID")));
select.SelectByValue("0");
```

**Edit**

The div containing your `select` element has the following style attribute:

```
style="display: none;"
```

Selenium acts like a user, if the user can't see an element, Selenium can't see it either.

There is a way to select an option using JavaScript, but the options are hidden for a reason, aren't they?

Anyway, here is how to select it using JavaScript:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('csscib_primary_i').value = 'value-you-want-to-select'");
```

Also, please don't post your code / html as an image, but as text. Makes it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: Its showing this same error : - "Cannot click on option element.Executing javascript function returned an un expected error,but no error could be returned from IE's javascript Enginge."

Comment: Make sure the zoom level of IE is at 100%, open IE click on the settings and set zoom to 100%. If this still doesn´t work, please provide some html as @DebanjanB suggested. IE can be a bit tricky when it comes to selecting `options`.

Comment: Updated in Question Area.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Still no luck. I'm not able to set the value to drop down by using your javascript Executer